# Why does the bucket of map in golang contain up to 8 key/elem pairs? Why the number is eight?

Tags: dictionary, go

https://golang.org/src/runtime/map.go
The following shows the comments in the golang map source code：

```golang
// This file contains the implementation of Go's map type.
//
// A map is just a hash table. The data is arranged
// into an array of buckets. Each bucket contains up to
// 8 key/elem pairs. The low-order bits of the hash are
// used to select a bucket. Each bucket contains a few
// high-order bits of each hash to distinguish the entries
// within a single bucket.
//
// If more than 8 keys hash to a bucket, we chain on
// extra buckets.
```

**Why the number is eight?**
image like this:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/co0Bg.png)

Is the reason similar to this https://laptrinhx.com/why-does-the-number-of-map-buckets-exceed-8-before-turning-into-a-red-black-tree-4063759990/

Comment: You have to chose some size. Do you have any number that would be better suited?

Comment: thanks for comment .
I just want to know the reason, just curious

Answer (score 2):

This comes from the [initial `hashmap.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/0c6b55e76ba6d59f57c81ca1160d833c79270753) from Go 1.4 (July 2014, [CL 99380043](https://codereview.appspot.com/99380043))

[Dave Cheney](https://dave.cheney.net/about) details that process in "[How the Go runtime implements maps efficiently (without generics)](https://dave.cheney.net/2018/05/29/how-the-go-runtime-implements-maps-efficiently-without-generics)"

> ### Go’s map is a hashmap
>
> A hashmap is a classic data structure offering O(1) lookups on average and O(n) in the worst case. That is, when things are working well, the time to execute the map function is a near constant.
>
> The size of this constant is part of the hashmap design and the point at which the map moves from O(1) to O(n) access time is determined by its hash function.
>
> 1. You need a hash function for the key.
> 2. You need an equality function to compare keys.
> 3. You need to know the size of the key and,
> 4. You need to know the size of the value because these affect the size of the bucket structure, which the compiler needs to know, as you walk or insert into that structure, how far to advance in memory.

[Ricardo Erikson](https://twitter.com/ricardoerikson) adds in "[Memory Allocation and Performance in Golang Maps](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/memory-allocation-and-performance-in-golang-maps-b267b5ad9217)".
He refers to [Alexander Kochetkov](https://twitter.com/avk_ai)'s article "[Some insights on Maps in Golang](https://hackernoon.com/some-insights-on-maps-in-golang-rm5v3ywh)", which adds:

> **Average number of items in buckets is called load factor**.
>
> Load factor divided by 2 will be the average lookup time, and collisions rate will define dispersion of it.
> Formally the complexity is still O(n), but in practice collisions is rare enough and keys will spread to buckets almost evenly.

Ricardo adds:

> A map in Go is a hash table that stores its key/value pairs into buckets. Each bucket is an array that holds up to 8 entries.
> The default number of buckets is 1.
>
> Once the number of entries across each bucket reaches an average load of buckets (aka load factor), the map gets bigger by doubling the number of buckets.
> Every time a map grows, it allocates memory for the new-coming entries.
>
> In practice, every time the load of the buckets reaches 6.5 or more, the map grows.  This value is hardcoded and was chosen to optimize memory usage.